On the divergence of $\{\cos(x\pi n!)\}$ for all $x\in \mathbb{R}-\{0\}$

It is well known that $\left\{\sin\left(n\right)\right\}$ and $\left\{\cos\left(n\right)\right\}$ are divergent sequences.
Recently I encountered with a problem where I needed to prove that $\cos\left(n!\right)$ was divergent. However, dealing with it, I realized that this was a particular case of the problem $\cos\left(x\pi n!\right)$: If $x = 1/\pi$, then I would get $\left\{\cos\left(n!\right)\right\}$.
And now, it was easy to see that
$\left\{\cos\left(x\pi n!\right)\right\}$ was a convergent sequence, converging to $1$ if $x$ was a rational number. But, I am still unable to prove that
$\left\{\cos\left(x\pi n!\right)\right\}$ diverges for irrational $x$.
I know that it is enough to verify this for
$x \in \left(0,1\right)$.

Any discussion in this regard or any solution is greatly appreciated.

For example if $x=2e$ the sequence $\cos (\pi x n!)$ converges to $1$

Oh! How? Can you please elaborate?

Just write $e=\sum 1/k!$ so $2en!=2m_n+O(1/n)$ so $\cos (2\pi en!)=\cos O(1/n)\to 1$ note that I strongly believe that $\cos (n!)$ indeed diverges but the study of $\cos (\pi xn!)$ is tricky

Oh! Wow! I never had thought that one could think in this direction. I am not that good in handling the 'O' notation. Yet. I could understand. If I am not wrong - your argument completely relies on the fact that the sequence $a_n = \sum\limits_{k=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{(n+1)(n+2)\dots(n+k)}$ goes to $0$ as $n\to \infty$, which is clearly visible as $0< a_n \leq \frac{1}{n}\to 0$ as $n\to 0$. Isn't it?

Correct - but one can replace $e$ with similar series - eg $\sum a_n/n!$ where $a_n$ integral (even), bounded and infinitely many nonzero so we do not get a rational etc - so lots of $x$ for which convergence happens; a better question is if we can have convergence to anything but $1$ (or potentially $-1$ as we may be able to arrange that all partial sums are odd ) for the cosine and anything but $0$ for the sine

Great. Thanks a lot!
